# Database migration - Old database to newly defined database

Tags: sql, database-migration

I have created new database for my client for his existing application. But now he wants his old data to be dumped in new database. Now I have many questions at this time as I am doing migration task for the first time. Below are my concerns and I don't know how to deal with them.

1. I have many new masters table which are not present in old db.
2. I have used different data types for primary key: int in new db but GUID in old db in most cases.
3. I have added extra columns in new db and removed old columns.
4. I have added many mapping table which are not there in old db.
5. Old db is storing value for data for 2 - 3 fields in 1 column (like    'india,MH,Pune' in 1 column) and I am storing it in different columns.

Can someone clear my concerns?

Comment: Which dbms, operating system(s) etc.

Comment: tables which aren't there in the old DB shouldn't be a problem, unless they have new relationships to old tables, and the new versions of those old tables have extra columns which need to be populated.

Comment: Anyway since this is quite a general question, in general you may be able to find schema mapping and comparison tools (e.g. such things exist definitely for Microsoft SQL Server, and maybe for others) which will help you map the differences and can assist in creating a migration script.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you'll approach this one of two ways. There are shades of gray; you'll probably find yourself using some mixture of these two approaches.

1. In the old database, create views that mimic the new database
   structure. Export the views from the old database, and import them
   into the new database.
2. Export data from the old database tables. Import data into a staging
   schema in the new database. (Create a staging schema with SQL's
   `create schema ...`) Write queries or stored procedures in the new
   database that transforms data from the staging tables to the new
   tables.

There are tools that can help. But you haven't identified your dbms, and tool recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.

In either case, you might have to add one or more columns to map old primary keys to new primary keys. For example, if your new tables don't already have a column for the old GUID, you might want to add a column in the new table for the old GUID. When you do that, you can always look up the right integer when you need to know it. (Use a SQL join, not a row-by-agonizing-row function.)

The point is to find a reliable way to get the right, new integer given only the old GUID. Many new database designers run into trouble with autoincrementing integers or sequences. Some do a remarkable amount of work before they realize their mistake. Don't be one of those people.